# GWT: Creating a new GWT Module in an existing webapp, or as a standalone entity

Tags: gwt, web-applications, module, eclipse-plugin

I created a sample GWT webapp using the Eclipse GWT plugin, and it runs perfectly.

But when I try adding a new module by,

1. Right-clicking my webapp project,
2. Selecting the *New | Other... | GWT Classes | Module* option; and
3. Clicking the *Next* button on the wizard

nothing happens - the wizard continues to remain on the same page!

I next copy-pasted the package/directory structure of my working webapp, and manually made suitable changes to the `NewModule.gwt.xml` and its contents; I also changed Java class names appropriately, and refreshed the Eclipse project.

But, now, when I run *GWT Compile* on the project (by right clicking the project in Eclipse), it only compiles the original webapp, completely ignoring my `NewModule` module that I manually created on the file-system.

**Question:**

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Is there a command-line method to ease the process of a new module-creation in an existing webapp, or, ideally, creating it as a stand-alone entity?

I'm using GWT 2.8.0 with Eclipse Neon, on Ubuntu 16.04. Have tried GWT 2.7.0 too, with same behavior as above.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this. Thankfully an event is logged which will give us some ideas:

```
Plug-in:   org.eclipse.ui
Serverity: Error
Message:   Unhandled event loop exception

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JarEntryFile cannot be cast to org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.modules.AbstractModule.getShortName(AbstractModule.java:294)
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.modules.AbstractModule.getQualifiedName(AbstractModule.java:272)
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.modules.ModuleJarResource.getQualifiedName(ModuleJarResource.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.modules.AbstractModule.getSimpleName(AbstractModule.java:342)
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.modules.ModuleJarResource.getSimpleName(ModuleJarResource.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.modules.ModuleUtils$3.visit(ModuleUtils.java:220)
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.modules.ModuleUtils$3.visit(ModuleUtils.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.modules.ModuleUtils.visitFragments(ModuleUtils.java:338)
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.modules.ModuleUtils.findModule(ModuleUtils.java:212)
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.wizards.NewModuleWizardPage.addCommonGWTModulesAsDefaultInherits(NewModuleWizardPage.java:367)
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.wizards.NewModuleWizardPage.moduleContainerChanged(NewModuleWizardPage.java:496)
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.wizards.NewModuleWizardPage.doFieldChange(NewModuleWizardPage.java:291)
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.wizards.NewModuleWizardPage.handleFieldChanged(NewModuleWizardPage.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewContainerWizardPage.containerDialogFieldChanged(NewContainerWizardPage.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewContainerWizardPage.access$1(NewContainerWizardPage.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewContainerWizardPage$ContainerFieldAdapter.dialogFieldChanged(NewContainerWizardPage.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.dialogfields.DialogField.dialogFieldChanged(DialogField.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.dialogfields.StringDialogField.setText(StringDialogField.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewContainerWizardPage.setPackageFragmentRoot(NewContainerWizardPage.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewContainerWizardPage.initContainerPage(NewContainerWizardPage.java:163)
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.wizards.NewModuleWizardPage.initModulePage(NewModuleWizardPage.java:328)
    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.wizards.NewModuleWizard.addPages(NewModuleWizard.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardSelectionPage.getNextPage(WizardSelectionPage.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardSelectionPage.getNextPage(WorkbenchWizardSelectionPage.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(WizardDialog.java:869)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5219)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4553)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4143)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:818)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:794)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor75.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:565)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:397)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5219)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4553)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4143)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:687)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
```

Followed by:

```
Session Data:

eclipse.buildId=4.6.1.M20160907-1200
java.version=1.8.0_112
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product --launcher.GTK_version 2
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product --launcher.GTK_version 2

This is a continuation of log file /home/user/workspace/.metadata/.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2017-05-02 11:19:21.409
```

There's nothing interesting/new in that `.bak_0.log` in my case. I've reported it to Eclipse and also logged issue [354](https://github.com/gwt-plugins/gwt-eclipse-plugin/issues/354) with [gwt-eclipse-plugin](https://github.com/gwt-plugins/gwt-eclipse-plugin/issues)

Edit: Of course this doesn't answer your real question, which I'll also see if I can help with.

Edit 2:

Since you've manually added your module, I'm going to assume that the IDE integration doesn't know about it. Right click on your project, go down to GWT then select Settings from the fold out instead of compile. Do you see your new module listed in the dialog? If not, add it and then see if GWT Compile starts working for you.

Regarding the command line, reference the [webAppCreator documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefCommandLineTools.html#webAppCreator).

Edit 3:

Okay, now I cannot reproduce your behavior. I started again the demo code then made a copy of it so that I have 2 modules in the same project. They don't inherit from each other or anything - scratch reference scratch/scratch2 references scratch2. I didn't create another html file to reference the second module. So here's my setup:

```
./src/scratch/server/GreetingServiceImpl.java
./src/scratch/shared/FieldVerifier.java
./src/scratch/client/Scratch_gwt.java
./src/scratch/client/GreetingService.java
./src/scratch/client/GreetingServiceAsync.java
./src/scratch/Scratch_gwt.gwt.xml

./src/scratch2/server/GreetingService2Impl.java
./src/scratch2/shared/FieldVerifier2.java
./src/scratch2/client/GreetingService2Async.java
./src/scratch2/client/Scratch2_gwt.java
./src/scratch2/client/GreetingService2.java
./src/scratch2/Scratch2_gwt.gwt.xml
```

I don't know if it's pertinent (somewhat doubt it), but I also modified my web.xml:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>scratch.server.GreetingServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>scratch2.server.GreetingService2Impl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/scratch_gwt/greet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/scratch_gwt/greet2</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

When I right click on my scratch-gwt project and go to GWT | Compile, I have:

```
Project: scratch-gwt
Log level: Info
Ouput style: Obfuscated
Entry Point Modules
    Scratch_gwt - scratch
    Scratch2_gwt - scratch2
```

I did have to add the Scratch2_gwt entry point here. And my compile output:

```
Compiling module scratch.Scratch_gwt
   Compiling 5 permutations
      Compiling permutation 0...
      Compiling permutation 1...
      Compiling permutation 2...
      Compiling permutation 3...
      Compiling permutation 4...
   Compile of permutations succeeded
   Compilation succeeded -- 11.274s
Linking into /home/user/workspace/scratch-gwt/war/scratch_gwt
   Link succeeded
   Linking succeeded -- 0.180s
Compiling module scratch2.Scratch2_gwt
   Compiling 5 permutations
      Compiling permutation 0...
      Compiling permutation 1...
      Compiling permutation 2...
      Compiling permutation 3...
      Compiling permutation 4...
   Compile of permutations succeeded
   Compilation succeeded -- 7.821s
Linking into /home/user/workspace/scratch-gwt/war/scratch2_gwt
   Link succeeded
   Linking succeeded -- 0.109s
```

So, I can only tell that that it is indeed possible to do this. Reverify your compilation settings and either start a new project from scratch to try again or post some of your configuration.

Comment: I have been seeing my `NewModule` listed in *Entry Point Modules* all this time. Only this time, I tried upping the Log Level from INFO to ALL. Made no difference - there's no mention of `NewModule` anywhere in the verbose log output generated by ALL. Thanks for flagging the issue with Eclipse and GWT teams. I will try `webAppCreator` next, but will wait some more before marking the response as final.